# Do both of these regular expressions

Tags: regex, automata, nfa

Consider the following NFA:

[image]

Are both of these regular expressions equivalent and generate the strings accepted by the NFA, or are they different?

```
1. a^* (Kleene star)
2. lambda + a^+ (Kleene plus)
```

I realize this seems trivial, as its a very simply NFA, but this comes from a more complex problem that I've reduced down to a very minimal example.

Comment: Don't know about NFA, but the regular expressions don't make sense to me - `^` indicates start-of-string anchor, and is not quantifiable, and what does `lambda +` mean? Or does that syntax mean something in the context of NFA?

Comment: I'm using the `^` symbol just to place the asterisk and the plus symbol up as superscripts, as I couldn't use mathjax on stack overflow to just show it.  And these are regular expressions in the notations used with formal languages, not the typical notation you would see in code.  `+` is union here and `lambda` is empty string.

Comment: So the first answer is "zero or more concatenations of a" and the second answer is "the union of lambda and one or more concatenations of a."

Comment: [cs.se] or [math.se] are probably better places to about NFA regular expressions. [so] is for programming questions.

Comment: The first is `a*` and the second is `(|a+)`. So they are both equal.

Comment: Duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/algorithm-to-determine-whether-two-regexes-are-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These regular expressions describe the same regular language. The reason for this is that `a^*` generates the empty string by repeating `a` zero times.